# Batch File EnableDelayedExpansion and Variable Setting

Tags: batch-file

I'm editing a batch file given to me and I'm not sure what the following line of code does:

set allKeys=%allKeys% !currentKey!

thanks!

Comment: You really should provide more of the code. It is impossible to predict what it does without knowing whether delayed expansion is enabled, whether the line is part of a block of code, etc. To guess as to the purpose might require the entire script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appends the run-time value of the variable `currentkey` after a space to the parse-time value of `allkeys` and assigns the result as the run-time value of `allkeys` - provided `delayedexpansion` is invoked. If `delayedexpansion` is not invoked, it appends the string `!currentKey!`, not the value of the variable `currentkey`.

Without any context information, we're guessing beyond that...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in code to try.

allkeys is set outside the for in do loop.

Inside the for in do loop it is changed but as it uses %allkeys% the changes are not cumulative.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set allkeys=one
for %%a in (two three four five six) do (
set currentkey=%%a
set allKeys=%allKeys% !currentKey!
echo allkeys is now "!allkeys!"
)
echo allkeys is now "%allkeys%" outside the loop
pause
```

Change this line
`set allKeys=%allKeys% !currentKey!`
to this and run it to see the difference.

```
set allKeys=!allKeys! !currentKey!
```

Answer (score 0):

For a decription of what delayed expansion *is*, type `SET /?`.